# Remember field values while editing the node

Tags: entities, nodes

I have a situation where i want to get the recently added value in the field while editing the node. For example: if i have a field called name where i enter the value initially, i want the field to have the recent value when i open the node to edit it. Can anyone please let me know how do we achieve it?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean with 'recently added value'. Are you talking about a default value for the field?

Comment: I'm using workflow module and workflow fields module which helps me to make fields visible and editable in particular state. Initially there is a default value "NA" in the field, i edit it for the first time with other value say "Hello" and when i open the node for next time the value in the field is still "NA". What i'm thinking is whenever i say the field is editable in particular state it is displaying the field as a new field. What do you think?

Comment: I have no experience with the workflow module I am afraid. It seems though, that the value isn't saved in the first place.